# How to select a textfield value in titanium for mobileweb?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am working on Titanium. I tried to select the value in a textfield programmatically like

`txtfieldObj.setSelection(0,value.length);`

It works for me in IOS and ANDROID but not in MOBILEWEB.
Can any one give an idea to implement this in Titanium MOBILEWEB.

Thanks in Advance,

Swathi.

Comment: According to the documentation (http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField) the setSelection method works on Android and iOs only. You can't use it in  a mobile web application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Robin, but is there any other way to select the value in the textfield for titanium mobileweb?